# Enable softlayer ohai plugin

Tags: chef-infra, ibm-cloud-infrastructure, ohai-gem

I wanted to enable the [softlayer ohai plugin](https://github.com/chef/ohai/blob/master/lib/ohai/plugins/softlayer.rb) so that the softlayer metadata will be collected.

I have included the `ohai` recipe in the chef node's run list. I can see it when I run

```
knife node show NODE_ID
```

The `softlayer.rb` file seems to be missing on the chef node at  `/opt/chef/embedded/apps/ohai/lib/ohai/plugins`. Lots of plugins are missing at that location. 
What might be wrong? What do I need to do to collect the softlayer metadata ?

Comment: What chef version are you using? It was added with [Ohai 8.6.0](https://github.com/chef/ohai/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#release-860) and is (at least) included in Chef 12.5.1.

Comment: I am using Chef Version: 12.1.2

Comment: Try upgrading to version >= 12.5.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to give ohai a [*hint*](https://docs.chef.io/ohai.html#hints). Therefore, create a file called `/etc/chef/ohai/hints/softlayer.json` with content `{}`.

Then, [this check](https://github.com/chef/ohai/blob/ac9f5a2ae4ada9f2e6e821418ed3a9039bda9a91/lib/ohai/plugins/softlayer.rb#L34) should trigger calls to the metadata service, which finally populates the automatic attributes.

For debugging purpose, try on the node:

```
ohai softlayer
```

After the chef run, these automatic attributes can be read from the chef server with:

```
knife node show <nodename> -a softlayer
```

Comment: running ohai softlayer on node gave error "ERROR: Encountered error while running plugins: #<Ohai::Exceptions::AttributeNotFound: No such attribute: 'softlayer'"

Comment: Probably because your chef version does not yet include this plugin. See my comment above.

Comment: Is there any way by which we can get the softlayer metadata with chef-version 12.1.2 ?

Comment: I did not compare the code in detail, but @coderanger's [ohai-softlayer cookbook](https://github.com/coderanger/ohai-softlayer) looks very similar.

Comment: Thanks .. I installed the https://github.com/coderanger/ohai-softlayer cookbook I can see that /etc/chef/ohai_plugins/softlayer.rb file ... I ran the command knife node show <node name> -a softlayer  and knife node show <node name> -a ohai-softlayer .. It did not show anything ... how to see all the softlayer attributes ?

Comment: Great. What was the mistake before?

Comment: I forgot to run knife node run_list add <NODE_NAME> ohai-softlayer :P

Comment: hi , I dont want the user_metadata attribute to be sent to chef_server. What is the best way to do this ?